# Error with showing data from Firebase in Listview

Tags: java, android, firebase, listview, firebase-realtime-database

Currently, I am trying to get an activity to work where a class is listed and  on click, it returns Users' names and grades  in a separate activity with a Listview. When, the user signs up for the class their uid is saved under the class. First, I am retrieving the uids' listed under the class name, which works.After that, I am using the uid to navigate back to the user information and retrieve the name and grade and combine it into one variable, so I can show it in a Listview. Unfortunately, when I run the app I get the error:

```
Can't convert object of type java.lang.String to type com.samuelford48gmail.thsconnect.User
```

When I ran the app in debug mode, it said that the name and grade were null. Also, when I used system.out.println to show the datasnapshot it only returned the Classes under the users' uid. I think part of the problem could be my structure in Firebase.

Here is my Firebase structure:

```
{
  "Science" : {
    "-LhrSfhNaQX1ZiNToeYQ" : {
  "Students" : {
    "-LhzXqvBPJl-gvN7bZ6c" : "9TKqqNqge5cKpFgjHByAFpZ3iRD2"
  },
  "date_clasname" : "dd",
  "room_number" : "dd",
  "teacher" : "dd",
  "uid" : "-LhrSfhNaQX1ZiNToeYQ"
},
"-LhrSfwx3nKd3DhRNJRp" : {
  "date_clasname" : "dd",
  "room_number" : "dd",
  "teacher" : "dd",
  "uid" : "-LhrSfwx3nKd3DhRNJRp"
},
"-LhrSg-4YJ52a1Zj9LoK" : {
  "Students" : {
    "-LhrfCKXsrjDWC4dJU8H" : "9TKqqNqge5cKpFgjHByAFpZ3iRD2"
  },
  "date_clasname" : "dd",
  "room_number" : "dd",
  "teacher" : "dd",
  "uid" : "-LhrSg-4YJ52a1Zj9LoK"
   }
  },
   "Users" : {
"9TKqqNqge5cKpFgjHByAFpZ3iRD2" : {
  "Classes" : {
    "-LhrfCKVETBZrgOIrCLR" : {
      "date_clasname" : "dd",
      "room_number" : "dd",
      "teacher" : "dd"
    },
    "-LhzWYnqD-qi8v-MFWKF" : {
      "date_clasname" : "dd",
      "room_number" : "dd",
      "teacher" : "dd"
    },
    "-LhzXqv0RZMts7Df1Ehg" : {
      "date_clasname" : "dd",
      "room_number" : "dd",
      "teacher" : "dd"
    }
  },
  "email" : "svhsdev@vigoschools.org",
  "grade" : "11",
  "name" : "Samuel"
},
"NnJlSVeqGXhJ2Nab2bhjr0HIpku2" : {
  "Classes" : {
    "-LhNEZI73xZWbu8tb4ZL" : {
      "date_clasname" : "March 5",
      "room_number" : "101",
      "teacher" : "pence"
    },
    "-LhNFH_LB8PGKKOML-Ta" : {
      "date_clasname" : "d",
      "room_number" : "",
      "teacher" : "s"
    },
    "-LhNFHjC0sYKaXd_OcX2" : {
      "date_clasname" : "d",
      "room_number" : "",
      "teacher" : "s"
    },
    "-LhrbM1htXYd0CxZiKMZ" : {
      "date_clasname" : "dd",
      "room_number" : "dd",
      "teacher" : "dd"

  },
  "email" : "samuelford48@gmail.com",
  "grade" : "12",
  "name" : "Samuel Ford"
},
}
 }
  }
```

Here is the code for the activity with the Listview that is attempting to get the user's name and grade:

```
public class admin_show_students_uid extends AppCompatActivity {

  private FirebaseDatabase database;
  private DatabaseReference myRef;
  String user_info = null;
  String name = null;
ListView lv;
ArrayList<String> list=new ArrayList<>();
@Override
protected void onCreate( Bundle savedInstanceState) {
    super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
    setContentView(R.layout.admin_show_students_uid);

    lv = (ListView) findViewById(R.id.lv_science_students);
    final ArrayAdapter<String> adapter=new ArrayAdapter<String>(this,android.R.layout.simple_list_item_1,list);
    lv.setAdapter(adapter);
    lv.setStackFromBottom(true);
    final String post_key = getIntent().getStringExtra("post_key");
    database = FirebaseDatabase.getInstance();
    myRef = database.getReference("Science").child(post_key).child("Students");
    myRef.addChildEventListener(new ChildEventListener() {
        @Override
        public void onChildAdded(@NonNull DataSnapshot dataSnapshot, String s) {
    //name gets the uid saved
            name = dataSnapshot.getValue(String.class);

      myRef = database.getReference("Users").child(name);

     getusersinfo();        
  adapter.notifyDataSetChanged();
        }

        @Override
        public void onChildChanged(@NonNull DataSnapshot dataSnapshot, @Nullable String s) {

        }

        @Override
        public void onChildRemoved(@NonNull DataSnapshot dataSnapshot) {

        }

        @Override
        public void onChildMoved(@NonNull DataSnapshot dataSnapshot, @Nullable String s) {

        }

        @Override
        public void onCancelled(@NonNull DatabaseError databaseError) {

        }
    });
}

public void getusersinfo(){
    myRef.addListenerForSingleValueEvent(new ValueEventListener() {
  @Override
        public void onDataChange(@NonNull DataSnapshot dataSnapshot) {
            for (DataSnapshot dataSnapshot2 : dataSnapshot.getChildren()) {
                User user = dataSnapshot2.getValue(User.class);
                String name = user.getName();
                String grade = user.getGrade();
             user_info = ("Name " + name + "Grade" + grade);
  list.add(user_info);

            }

        }

        @Override
        public void onCancelled(@NonNull DatabaseError databaseError) {

           }
       });

    }
  }
```

Thank you in advance and let me know if you have any questions about my code!

Comment: Can you please format your database schema in question or at least provide a screenshot?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The problem is that you got a reference to the specific user, but within `getuserinfo()` you are iterating over its attributes. Instead, just get `User` from `dataSnapshot`. See:

```
public void getusersinfo(){
    studentRef.addListenerForSingleValueEvent(new ValueEventListener() {
        @Override
        public void onDataChange(@NonNull DataSnapshot dataSnapshot) {
            User user = dataSnapshot.getValue(User.class);
            String email = user.getName();
            String grade = user.getGrade();
            user_info = ("Name " + email + "Grade" + grade);
            list.add(user_info);               
        }

        @Override
        public void onCancelled(@NonNull DatabaseError databaseError) {

        }
    });
}
```

Comment: That doesn't work and doesn't really make sense. The point of the getusersinfo method is to return the name and grade of the respective uid and then add it to the array for the listview.

Comment: Sorry, there was miss-understanding. Found the problem and updated my answer @Samuel

Comment: Thank you...that successfully returns user_info but the array size keeps  returning 0 for some reason, so my listview is blank.

Comment: You should update your `ListView` inside the `onDataChanged` method. Because Firebase's ValueEventListener works asynchronously @Samuel